# Yosemiteで、bundle installを行うと、nokogiri install時にlibxml2 is missingのエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

OSはYosemiteです。
railsに関するコマンドを入力すると

```
Could not find nokogiri-1.6.5 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

と出るので、bundle installを行うと、libiconv, libxml2 is missingのエラーが置きます。

```
gem install nokogiri
```

はうまくいきインストールされるのですが、bundle installが出来ません。

```
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -llibxml2... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  Please locate mkmf.log to investigate how it is failing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.
................................................
................................................
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

コマンドラインツールスもインストールして、libiconv, libxml2もそれぞれインストールして、brew linkも行いました。
何が原因か分からず、１週間ほどこのエラーに悩んでいます。

Comment: `brew install libxml2`してからインストールしたらうまくいくのでは？

Answer (score 1):

エラーログを見ると、Bundlerで必要なのは 1.6.5 のようです。

`gem install nokogiri`すると最新のgemを取ってくるので1.6.5がインストールされないのではないでしょうか？

エラーログにもあるように`gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.5'`とバージョンを指定してインストールしてみてください。

（ちなみに`gem search nokogiri -l`でインストールされているnokogiriのバージョンが確認できます。）

で、おそらく`gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.5'`しても同じようなエラーが出ると思います。

僕の場合、nokogiriをインストールする場合はこんなオプションを付けてインストールします。

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.5' -- --use-system-libraries
```

これでもダメならネットの各種情報をあたってみてください。

たとえばQiitaにもたくさんnokogiri installに関する情報が載ってます。

http://qiita.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=rel&q=nokogiri+install+libxml2+is+missing&sort=rel

他にも「nokogiri yosemite 1.6.5 libxml2 is missing」のようなキーワードでネットを検索してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

You need to install missing development dependencies by:

```
xcode-select --install
```

See: [gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8.1' fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39937394/55075)

For Ubuntu, see: [nokogiri failing to upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30425210/55075).